# Equidistant scaling for X,Y and Z axes in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

how can I get an equidistant scaling for the X,Y and Z axis in a Matplolib 3D plot?

I already tried this:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', aspect='equal')
```

But this only results in a equidistant scaling of the X and Y axis. How can I apply this to all three axes?

Thanks!

Comment: here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/python-matplotlib-plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector/11156353#11156353

Answer (score 0):

There's a very flexible example with [arbitrary scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326371/setting-aspect-ratio-of-3d-plot) and a [really short example with equidistant scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300650);  these don't work for you?